# Combine wsdl with xsd to single wsdl

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl

I have wsdl that includes many xsds

```
  <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="Name/Space">

         <xsd:include schemaLocation="role.xsd"/>
         <xsd:include schemaLocation="status.xsd"/>
         <xsd:include schemaLocation="datetime.xsd"/>  
...
```

Can I combine wsdl with all xsds into single wsdl?

Comment: why would u want to do that? I personally prefer separate xsd files.

Comment: Bug in JBoss makes me to do this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using XSLT transformation I do it